# Reduce time between each kill() function in C

Tags: c, signals, kill, pid

Hi does anyone know a way to send signal SIGUSR1/2 without loss to another pid ?

the problem is when i put kill(pid, SIGUSR1) in a while loop, my other program recieve only few of them, its seems there is a loss and i have to wait between two calls to kill().
Im actually forced to used usleep() in my loop in order to receive all the SIGUSR signals ive sent.
I'd like to recieve all of them as fast as it is possible.

Thx.

Comment: It sounds like you are using signals for a purpose for which they weren't intended. I would recommend a different form of IPC, like pipes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `sigaction()` rather than `signal()` because `sigaction()` can control which signals are  blocked while the current signal is being handled.  Also, your receiver has to process each signal received; that is relatively costly compared to sending a signal, so your killer (signalling) process can outrun the 'killed' (receiving) process with ease.  You should think about why you are needing to send so many signals.  They are a mechanism to use in special circumstances.

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot use sigaction(), i mean its a school exercise and this function is forbidden. Why i need to send so many signal is because i'm sending char with signal(SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2) to an other program(receiver) using his pid, i have a signal handler function which set bit in a char 1 or 0 with reception of SIGUSR2 /SIGUSR1 and print the char when 8 signals have been received. i mean SIGUSR1 is sent if a bit is set (my_char & (1 << current_bit)) with (0 < current_bit < 7) and SIGUSR2 is sent if (my_char & (0 << current_bit).

Comment: btw what do you mean by "your receiver has to process each signal received" ?

Comment: @Mickael: well, I assume that you are sending the signals so that they can be counted, which means that the receiver has to be interrupted and the signal handler that does the counting invoked and then control returns where things left off.  This takes time - more time than sending the signal.  Even if 'all' the receiver does inside the handler is add one to a counter.

Comment: So you said that the program who receives the signals should return to my program who send signal if he received each signal ? a kind of (server)"ok ive received the data, im waiting now for next signal" and (client)"now i know that you receive the signal im sending the next one"

Comment: @Mickael: no, that was not my intention.  My suggestion is that you should not be using signals to communicate between processes in the manner described.  It is silly - your tutor is making you do a pointless exercise.  The name of the function call you use - `kill()` - should be an indication that it is not something to use lightly and frivolously.  It has serious implications for the receiving process.  Trying to communicate via signals is an abuse of the system call.  You use signals to communicate exceptional circumstances.  You don't try to use it as a high-bandwidth IPC channel.

Comment: @Mickael: continuing...All else apart, it is anything but high bandwidth; you can communicate approximately 1 bit per signal sent, and that is dire. Also, proscribing the use of `sigaction()` immediately renders everything unreliable. The `signal()` function gives you unreliable signal handling; that is why there is `sigaction()` to give you reliable signal handling. Yes, you can communicate between processes with signals, but you don't if you can avoid it. If you learned from the exercise that you don't do this, then it has a purpose. I trust it was the intended purpose of the exercise!

Comment: @Jonathan: thx for explaining me all that stuff, i understand that i should not use these signals that way and now i think that aim of the exercise is a kind of exploitation of signals SIGUSR1/2

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: I don't think the exercise is totally without value - for one thing, it illustrates why signals should often be avoided, and for another it serves as a good introduction to the idea of a covert channel.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for guaranteed delivery of exactly same amount of signals. If you send two or more SIGUSR1 while other process blocked and can't handle first of them, or processing previous instance of this signal, or have this signal blocked, all but one signals are lost: there is bitmask for pending signals in kernel, not array of counters.

You can only hope to receive as much of them as possible.

Comment: So if i call 800 time kill() for 100 char, is it just the system that cannot handle to receive 800 signals for a single PID? or is there also a limitation when i send signals? im wondering if the limitation is when i send or when i receive signal ?

Comment: Limitation is on receiving end: there is only one bit for marking signal pending. kill() would just set it to 1 again and again at any rate.

Answer (score 0):

There are the so-called real-time signals. These have a queue and unless you overflow the queue you are guaranteed to receive one signal for each signal sent. These are the signals in the range 34-64 or to be portable, SIGRTMIN - SIGRTMAX.

However, if your assignment is to use SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 then maybe you're supposed to be learning about unreliable data transmission. The same sort of problems happen in electrical circuits. If a latch is already set by an electrical signal then a second signal has no effect until the latch is read and cleared. This is why serial and parallel ports have clocks and/or acknowledgement signals.